# How can I ingest metrics that match either rule in metric_relabel_configs?

Tags: prometheus

For example:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [namespace]
  separator: ;
  regex: (?i)(ns1|ns2)
  replacement: $1
  action: keep
- source_labels: [__name__]
  separator: ;
  regex: (?i)(kube_node_status_capacity_pods)
  replacement: $1
  action: keep
```

I want to keep `kube_node_status_capacity_pods`, although it's not coming from either of the two namespaces `ns1` or `ns2`, and only keep other metrics from those namespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can or the expressions together into one action:

```
- source_labels: [namespace, __name__]
  regex: ((ns1|ns2);.*)|(.*;kube_node_status_capacity_pods)
  action: keep
```